# Search Image by specified size

Tags: html, image, search, google-image-search

I got some help a while ago to make something that searches for images on google with a preset size. Now I want to know if it would be possible to change this HTML5 so that you can type in your own size to use instead of a preset one. So if I type **54** in a text box labeled **width** and **10** in one labeled **height**, I would only get results with images that have a width of **54** and a height of **10**.

```
<form action="https://www.google.com/search" method="get">
   <input name="tbm" value="isch" type="hidden">
   <input name="tbs" value="isz:ex,iszw:10328,iszh:7760" type="hidden">
   <input name="q" size="35" type="text" placeholder="zelda">
   <input type="submit" value="Find 10K images">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    function addSpecs() {
        document.getElementsByName("tbs")[0].value =
            "isz:ex,iszw:"
            + document.getElementById("w").value
            + ",iszh:"
            + document.getElementById("h").value;
    }
</script>
<form action="//www.google.com/search" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="tbm" value="isch" />
    <input type="hidden" name="tbs" value="" />
    w: <input type="text" id="w" /><br />
    h: <input type="text" id="h" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="q" size="35" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Find images" onclick="addSpecs();" />
 </form>
```